# 2D array bubble pop

Tags: java, arrays

My assignment is making carnival bubble pop game. The rule is throwing darts 15 times and add up the score then display the prize. And I want my darts to be one dart at one space. But when I run my code some column has 2 or 3 darts and I can't figure out the

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Declares a 9 X 9 Game Board of colored "Balloons"
    String[][] bpBoard = { 
    {"R","G","B","R","G","B","R","G","B"}, 
    {"G","B","R","G","B","R","G","B","R"}, 
    {"B","R","G","B","R","G","B","R","G"},
    {"R","G","B","R","G","B","R","G","B"}, 
    {"G","B","R","G","B","R","G","B","R"}, 
    {"B","R","G","B","R","G","B","R","G"},
    {"R","G","B","R","G","B","R","G","B"}, 
    {"G","B","R","G","B","R","G","B","R"}, 
    {"B","R","G","B","R","G","B","R","G"} };
 
    // Prints the game board prior to any game play 
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    for(int r = 0; r<bpBoard.length; r++){
      for(int c = 0; c < bpBoard[0].length; c++){
        System.out.print(" " + bpBoard[r][c] + " ");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }

    // write code to throw 15 random "darts". Replace the colored "balloons" and add to the counters as directed.
    for(int i = 0; i<15; i++){
  row = (int) (5 * Math.random());
  col = (int) (5 * Math.random());
bpBoard[row][col] = bpBoard[row][col] + "*";

}
System.out.println();


    // Redisplay your game board 
for(int r = 0; r<bpBoard.length; r++){
  for(int c = 0; c<bpBoard[0].length; c++){
    System.out.print(" [" + bpBoard[r][c] + "] ");
  }//end of col loop
System.out.println();
}//end of row loop

    // print out the prize that you won based on the directions 
int red = 0;
int green = 0;
int blue = 0;
```

If I run the code it looks like this

```
R  G  B  R  G  B  R  G  B 
 G  B  R  G  B  R  G  B  R 
 B  R  G  B  R  G  B  R  G 
 R  G  B  R  G  B  R  G  B 
 G  B  R  G  B  R  G  B  R 
 B  R  G  B  R  G  B  R  G 
 R  G  B  R  G  B  R  G  B 
 G  B  R  G  B  R  G  B  R 
 B  R  G  B  R  G  B  R  G 

 [R*]  [G*]  [B*]  [R*]  [G**]  [B]  [R]  [G]  [B] 
 [G]  [B]  [R]  [G*]  [B*]  [R]  [G]  [B]  [R] 
 [B*]  [R]  [G]  [B]  [R]  [G]  [B]  [R]  [G] 
 [R*]  [G*]  [B]  [R]  [G*]  [B]  [R]  [G]  [B] 
 [G**]  [B]  [R*]  [G]  [B]  [R]  [G]  [B]  [R] 
 [B]  [R]  [G]  [B]  [R]  [G]  [B]  [R]  [G] 
 [R]  [G]  [B]  [R]  [G]  [B]  [R]  [G]  [B] 
 [G]  [B]  [R]  [G]  [B]  [R]  [G]  [B]  [R] 
 [B]  [R]  [G]  [B]  [R]  [G]  [B]  [R]  [G]
```

And below is the game rule/assignment

Bubble Pop Game This program is based on a carnival game that simulates a player throwing a dart at a 9 X 9 board covered with different colored balloons. If a set number of balloons are popped, the player will win a specific prize.

For this game, the board will contain RED (R), GREEN (G) and BLUE (B) balloons. Darts will be randomly thrown at the board and depending on the color balloon that is popped, the balloon will be changed from the color to a symbol to show that the space has been "taken" already.

When all of the darts have been thrown, the score will be tallied and the prizes will be awarded.

Calculate your score as follows:

If there is a RED "Balloon" in the space, add one to a RED counter & replace it with the @ symbol
If there is a GREEN "Balloon" in the space, add one to a GREEN counter & replace the G with the # symbol
if there is a BLUE "Balloon" in the space, add one to a BLUE counter and replace the B with a $ symbol
Prizes are awarded for the following scores: LARGE Prize is awarded if the RED Counter >= 12 MEDIUM Prize is awarded if GREEN Counter >= 10 SMALL Prize is awarded if BLUE Counter >= 8 Otherwise, no prize is awarded.

NOTE: You only get ONE prize, even if you pop enough balloons for additional prizes.

As with any carnival game, the goal is to win the LARGEST Prize possible!

Comment: If you're only trying to throw one dart per column, what are you doing throwing fifteen darts when there are only nine columns?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly to avoid being re-marked, You can just add an if condition.
I changed your 2nd for loop a little.

```
for(int i = 0; i<15;i++){
     boolean statement = false;
     row = random.nextInt(9);
     col = random.nextInt(9);
     do{
         if(bpBoard[row][col] == "*"){
            row = random.nextInt(9);
            col = random.nextInt(9);
         statement = true;
        }else{statement = false;}
     }while(statement);
     
     bpBoard[row][col] = "*";
 }
```

by doing this you set a new row and column value if assigned values have already been assigned. So you don't select same point again. If I understand something wrong for this part forgive me but if you want to throw one dart per column you need fifteen column and in this situation the for loop i shared can be changed. But idea is roughly same. if you avoid re-marked situation basicly you can store selected column number and if same number randomly generated you can regenerate it.